# Making a prepared statement for a query with no distinct attribute selected

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I already know how to make a prepared statement where we are inserting to or outputting a distinct attribute in a table for example

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $firstname);
```

But how can I write a statement for a query that is being used to populate a drop-down list, where no specific column/attribute is selected

```
$sql_coalition = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT coalition FROM candidates");
    while ($row = $sql_coalition->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['coalition'] . ">" . $row['coalition'] . "</option>";
    }
```

thanks

Comment: There is no real need or benefit in preparing a statement that has no parameters. What you have is fine

Comment: Unless of course you were intending to run that query many more times than once!

Comment: Plus, it might make sense to make this into a prepared statement even if it doesn’t use parameters, simply for consistency ...